# Other active component principles of operation

Tags: components, active-components

Besides valves and transistors...

On another question, someone talked about magnetic amplifiers, but they are slow.

Are there any other kind of "would-be" transistors out there ?

A transistor that does not work on semiconductor principles, nor thermionic emission principles, does another principle of operation exist?

Comment: Slow = ? | What spec is acceptable? Why are you asking? Without enough data the answer tends to be "Octarine".

Comment: Anything non linear that is fast enough for you and that can be "modulated" is a potential candidate. Optical cells - polarisation - refractive index change - cavity characteristic modifcations. Neutron bombardment :-) (boom boom!).

Answer (score 2):

Other possibilities are parametric amplifiers, tubes that work on ionization principles rather than thermionic emission (eg. cold cathode thyratrons, krytrons), spark gaps (as used in Marx generators), relays, motor-driven variacs, etc.